# WPF Workaround to add Window control as a child of visual

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a requirement to add a Window control inside a panel.

Of course this doesn't seem possible:
Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.

The problem boils down to drawing the Window Chrome (control box, title bar, minimize/restore/close button and borders) inside a panel using the OS theme configured by the user. Are there any workarounds I should be investigating?

Answer (score 1):

This is what User Controls are for - creating controls that can be reused in multiple windows.  Refactor your Window Control so that it is just a Window that contains a single User Control (which in turn contains everything your window previously had).  Place the User Control in your Panel.  The idea is that your current window (that you want to be a child, we'll call it Window B) looks something like this:

`Window B -> Grid/Panel -> Other Controls`

And should instead look like this

`Window B -> Grid/Panel -> User Control B -> Grid/Panel -> Other Controls`

And now other other window can look like this:

`Window A -> Grid/Panel -> ... -> Panel -> User Control B`

---

If you're trying to achieve an MDI like interface, you have a few options - use tab controls, use a panel that can be dragged and/or resized, etc.  In this case, you would **still** want a User Control, so that it could easily be reused in different windows (or panels) that you create, especially if you end up having to create those panels programatically (e.g. if you intend to create multiple instances dynamically at runtime).

In this case, you'll probably want **two** user controls: one that has all the controls from your other window, and one that would act as a "window" control within your main window.  The "Window" control would have functionality for resizing, docking, etc.

WPF does not support creating a window as if it were a control, or as a child of another window (the closest you can get to that is having a window be shown as a modal dialog).

Comment: It seems you don't understand the problem. Read the last paragraph of my question. The difficulty is drawing the Window Chrome  (control box, title bar, minimize/restore/close button and borders) inside a panel. How would you draw all these controls using the system theme inside a user control? Your answer doesn't provide any clue to do that. In your notation this is what I'm trying to achieve: Grid/Panel -> Window A. Where Window A includes every element of a Window, control box, border, title bar, minimize button etc..

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood.  I thought you had identified the reason this isn't going to work.  Are you trying to achieve a MDI style application?  WPF doesn't really support that.  For WPF, a window can't be a child of another window unless as a modal dialog.

Comment: Great you understand perfectly. It's indeed a scenario similar to MDI but I only need to display the window, ie: the Window Controls don't work. It's for a theme builder editor window where the user see the preview of his changes in real time.

Comment: Not sure you understood my last comment. I don't need any MDI functionality, resizing, docking etc. is out of scope of my requirements. I  need to render the Window. Your answer still miss that part. Where you say 'one that would act as a "window" control', How would you do the RENDERING of the window control. Not possible to put a window inside a panel, so I asked for workarounds. EX 1. create window, render window as Bitmap, put bitmap inside panel. 2. Create modeless dialog, disable user input on modeless dialog, dynamically  position the modelesse dialog to be above my theme editor dialog.

Comment: Here is an example from Windows 7: http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/14561d1245180930-window-color-appearance-change-3d_objects.jpg

Answer (score -5):

As the only answer is completely off topic, here is the best answer I can come up with:
Create window, render window as Bitmap, put bitmap inside panel.